# Can the root module in a gradle + java project contain source files?

Tags: java, gradle, build-process

I am new to gradle, and my task is to convert a legacy multi module Ant project to gradle. The project's structure is flat - no module/sub-module hierarchy, but we do have dependencies between the modules.
As far as I understand, a Gradle build has to have a root module - so that building the root would mean building the entire project. 
The "root" of the ant build was simply the module that depended on all the others - and building it built the entire project.
Can I use the same logic with gradle, or do i need to create a root module that doesn't contain any java source files? Even if it's possible, is it recommended?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be short, yes the root may contain source code as any other module. If it is recommended or not depends on your project. The only advantage of a special root module is that your find it more easily. As far as I know there is no real best practice to this decision.